# C# JSON Десериализация

Tags: c#, json, десериализация

Всем привет!
Имеется json пример:

```
{
  "ID": "",
  "record": [
    {
      "applicationdate": "2022-09-13",
    }
  ]
}
```

Имеются кейсы на проверку сервера, и при негативных кейсах, необходимо проверить то, что сервер будет принимать в себя только необходимый тип данных.
Cоответственно, вместо данных типа **string** мы будем отправлять **int** и наоборот, при этом название полей остается прежним.
Вопрос как можно избежать дублирование кода, объявляя объекты.

Пример десериализации:

```
partial class As
{
    public List<ACross> agreementsData;

    
    public Agreements()
    {
        agreementsData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InputData>
            (File.ReadAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\" + @"pathJson", Encoding.Default))
            .InputDataForCross;
    }
}

class InputData
{
    public List<ACross> InputDataForCross { get; set; }
}
```

Ну и соответственно классы с эмуляцией json объекта с полями:

```
 public class AgreementCross
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public List<AgreementItems> record { get; set; }
}

public class AgreementItems
{
    public string applicationdate { get; set; }
}
```

Вопрос, как быть если я не знаю какой тип данных будет у поля applicationdate, была идея использовать обощения, но можно ли как то обойтись без них? Чтобы по 100 не объявлять по факту одни и те же объекты.

Comment: `public DateTime applicationdate` - вот так должно быть, судя по json, который вы показали.

Comment: Можно использовать анонимные типы: `new { ID = "foo", record = 42 }`

Comment: `вместо данных типа string мы будем отправлять int и наоборот, при этом название полей остается прежним` нормальные разработчики так не делают. Как минимум потому что вам придется обрасти костылями из-за этого, а будущие коллеги наложат на вас неснимаемое проклятие.

Comment: таков кейс)) вот я и пытаюсь от этого отойти

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно все понял, вы пишете интеграционные тесты на api-метод сервера, где вы хотите проверить, что json-объект, который отправляется через POST-запрос, не может быть обработан сервером, если его поля имеют неверный тип.

Один из вариантов - использовать [ExpandoObject](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/9.2.php):

```
dynamic input = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
input.ID = "1"; // также можно писать input.ID = 1, input.ID = true и т.д.
input.record = "oops";

var jsonInput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input);
```

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду не использовать дефолт json, который в качестве входных данных используется в кейсе, а сформировать свой?

Comment: @Илья Вообще, я точно не знаю, какую цель вы преследуете, но в целом, да. Если дадите больше информации о том, чего вы пытаетесь добиться (даже неработающим псевдо-кодом), возможно, смогу дать больше полезной информации

Comment: Ну смотрите, есть кейс от тестировщика, позитивный и негативный, структура наименования полей в json остается одинаковой, меняется только тип данных, соответственно, при десериализации тип данных должен быть строго типизирован иначе будет Exeption, тестов на проверку 1 объекта довольно много и у меня получается по факту дублирование кода. Вы правы, в данном случае проверяю сервер на то, что эти данные ему не подойдут

Comment: @Илья а тип данных меняется только у одного поля `applicationdate`? И какую библиотеку для тестирования вы используете (NUnit, XUnit, другое)?

Comment: NUnit, тип меняется у всех

Comment: @Илья - анонимные типы! `new { ID = "foo", record = 42 }` - здесь ID - string, record - int. `new { ID = 1.5, record = DateTime.Now }` - здесь ID - double, record - DateTime. Таким образом элементарно задавать любые данные, не создавая ненужные классы.

Comment: @Илья постараюсь дополнить ответ, но уже не сегодня

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать)